# Google Maps Geocode get both locality and administrative_area when named equal

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I've a problem with the Google geocoder, when searching for `Barcelona` which could resolve to the province (`administrative_area`) of Barcelona, or the Barcelona city (`locality`) I only get the later with the Google API.

I would like to retrieve both places in a single API call to Google. Not sure if it's possible, I've looked their API and I didn't found anything.

Comment: Are you using the Android Geocoder or the Geocoding API?

Comment: @steve-benett Google Maps JS API v3 Geocoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the same with the [Geocoding API web-service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en). This request

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=barcelona&sensor=false

also gives the city data as a response, even with using different `component filters`.
I tried to geocode New York for a comparison:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new+york&sensor=false

The result is the same. It seems if a city and a region exists, the response contains only the city (the last link in the hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'll try working it out with two calls.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make two API calls, one with "Barcelona", and another one with "Barcelona region", so that I get both results, the `locality` and the `administrative_area`. But as said, it would be preferable to do it in a single API call.